# jQuery price calculating doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the script for calculating the price:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    updateSubtotal();
    updateDifferences();
});

function updateSubtotal() {
    var subtotal = 0;
    var start = 32;
    $('.math1').each(function(i, el) {
        subtotal += parseFloat($(this).find('option:selected').data('price')*start);
    });
    $('#display').text(subtotal);
};

function updateDifferences() {
    $('.math1').each(function(i,sel) {
        var $sel = $(sel);
        $sel.find('option').each(function(j,opt) {
            var $opt = $(opt),
                optprice = $opt.data('price'),
                selprice = $sel.find('option:selected').data('price'),
                diff = optprice * selprice,
                diffamount = Math.abs(diff) || "";
            $opt.find('.diffaddsubtr').text(diffaddsubtr).end()
        });
    });
};

});
```

I use in every select option *2 writer as data-price="2" it works fine until it has to calculate the price of multiple selects: than it will do this

```
<select>
    <option data-price="2">calculate total with *2</option><!--selected-->
    <option data-price="5">calculate total with *5</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option data-price="9">calculate total with *3</option><!--selected-->
    <option data-price="3">calculate total with *9</option>
</select>
```

It has to do this 32(=var start)*(3*2) = 192 but it will do this: 32(=var start)*(2+3) = 160(=wrong) How can I solve this?

Comment: In the second select: your data attributes don't match the value of the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply, not add, in `updateSubtotal`

```
function updateSubtotal() {
    var subtotal = 32;
    $('.math1').each(function(i, el) {
        subtotal *= parseFloat($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
    });
    $('#display').text(subtotal);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
var totalMult = 0;
$('.math1').each(function(i, el) {
    totalMult += parseFloat($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
});
subtotal = totalMult*start;
```